Multiply Release Quantity by Newly Set Required Quantity (1.00) in Material Wizard 2 Screen (AM300020)
Hi I have done a customization where I set the required qty to 1.00 in the material wizard 2 screen which works, I now need to make sure the release qty field also reflects this change where release qty needs to be the 1.00*the BOM, it still seems to be the original qty * the BOM with the logic I have written below.
using System;
using PX.Data;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using PX.Objects.Common.Extensions;
using PX.Objects;
using PX.Objects.AM;

namespace PX.Objects.AM
{
  public class MatlWizard2_Extension : PXGraphExtension<PX.Objects.AM.MatlWizard2>
  {
    #region Event Handlers

 // Use RowSelected to update QtyReq when the row is selected or edited
        protected void AMWrkMatl_RowSelected(PXCache sender, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e)
        {
            var row = (AMWrkMatl)e.Row;
            if (row == null) return;

            // Force QtyReq to 1.00 whenever a row is selected or edited
            row.QtyReq = 1.00m;
            sender.SetValue<AMWrkMatl.qtyReq>(row, 1.00m);

            // Optional: add debugging info here for verification
            PXTrace.WriteInformation("AMWrkMatl_RowSelected: Setting QtyReq to 1.00");

            // Perform the MatlQty calculation
            if (row.QtyReq != null && row.BaseQtyReq != null)
    {
       // Check if it's a byproduct, if so, reverse the sign
        var qty = Math.Abs(row.QtyReq.GetValueOrDefault()) * (row.IsByproduct.GetValueOrDefault() ? -1 : 1);
        var baseQty = Math.Abs(row.BaseQtyReq.GetValueOrDefault()) * (row.IsByproduct.GetValueOrDefault() ? -1 : 1);

        // Set MatlQty based on QtyReq and BaseQtyReq (similar to original code logic)
        row.MatlQty = qty * baseQty;
        sender.SetValue<AMWrkMatl.matlQty>(row, row.MatlQty);

        PXTrace.WriteInformation($"Calculated MatlQty: {row.MatlQty}");
    }

        }
         
    #endregion
  }
}

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

I would not use RowSelected for setting any values. It should be for visual UI changes (Enabled, visible, etc.). In your example I would override MatlWizard1.ProcessMatlWork and change (not in cache) the passed in AMProdItem.BaseQtyToProd value to 1 for all orders being processed. This will simulate what the user can do in the UI (change wizard 1 qty so wizard 2 material is all based on qty 1)
